# Ffmpeg images to video

Tags: ffmpeg

I merge images with ffmpeg.
I use command

```
ffmpeg -v -y -r 12.245451/1 -i /tmp/images/img%03d.jpg -i /tmp/sounds/sound.3gp -vcodec mpeg4 out.avi
```

with -r I want to tell ffmpeg that I want to have 12.245451 images per second. It works only if I call ffmpeg with int values like -r 12/1. How can I tell ffmpeg -r 12.245451?

The problem is that actual rate is 12.245451 if I pass -r 12/1, sound shifts. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You want pass a fractional value with the option -r.

Transform -r 12.245451 
To
-r 12245451/10000000

It should be ok.